# Share HTML and associated files without a web server

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

I have a locally-stored HTML file and some of the usual associated files (like a subfolder containing images). I would like to let somebody else view these files through a web browser.

Obviously I could stick them on a website somewhere, but I don’t have one handy at the moment. I hoped instead I could use file sharing features of cloud storage apps. However, iCloud doesn’t allow folders to be shared (only files) and Dropbox insists that the other user downloads the Dropbox app (on my iPhone, at least).

Any other ideas which don’t involve a ton of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub seems to be what you are searching for.
I would explain it, but this guy does it better
and he has examples.
This is by Jnanaranjan Sahu, 
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-host-a-single-HTML-page

I think this should work.

His post is about 1/3 down the page.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Of course it wasn’t as straightforward to set up as, say, clicking a “Share” button on something like Dropbox, but it provides the end user experience I was looking for. I’ll accept this as the answer. The Quora page you linked to has a few alternative solutions as well which I might check out at some point.

Comment: Hey No problem, glad I was able to help you out!

Comment: Cloudflare Pages work much like GitHub pages.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive should work.
you can share a file then give people a link to the file.

Comment: I forgot about Google Drive! You’re right, it does share the folder OK but unfortunately it shows the HTML as the source code and there doesn’t seem to be much of a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776324/opening-html-from-google-drive

Comment: if they downloaded the HTML with the files to, Lets say their desktop, will it still function correctly? It would require them downloading it which does defeat the whole web part of it, but it might work as a temporary solution.

Comment: Yes, that would work on a computer but not necessarily on a phone. Ideally I just want a link that somebody can click on any device and the content will appear – no further steps.

Comment: For dropbox on your iphone, you can "Request Desktop Site" see if that works

Comment: Good thinking, @Pancakedinner, but it still forces you to sign up to Dropbox (PS hope you enjoyed your pancakes!)

Answer (score 1):

As @Pancakedinner said, Google Drive will work, but if you prefer not to use Google, or don't have a Google account, but if you have a Microsoft live account, you can sign into that and send it through "Onedrive.live.com".

Comment: Thanks, I just tried OneDrive (I have far too many cloud accounts!) and it certainly does the sharing bit as well as Google Drive. It also renders the HTML but excludes any external links to images, CSS etc. So it’s the best option so far but perhaps I’m just going to have to get some web space somewhere and do it the old fashioned way where a browser can display web files in a standard way without all these cloud services layering limitations over the top!